# axios put request to edit user in strapi.io not working

Tags: reactjs, request, axios, strapi

I'm trying to update the user avatar using axios PUT in strapi.io. I'm initially getting the user data on the componentDidmount.

the initial state

```
first_name: "Foo"
last_name: "Bar"
address: "456 address"
city: "City Address"
country: "Philippines"
zipcode: "1234"
error: ""
avatar: "https://limitless-brushlands-81295.herokuapp.com/uploads/ed4648185e1e425c884beabb99a92695.png"
```

this is the code when the user will submit the edited data

```
handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    const {first_name,last_name,address,city,country,zipcode,avatar} = this.state
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      address,
      city,
      country,
      zipcode
    };
    console.log(data)
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();

    bodyFormData.append('files.image', avatar)
    bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));

    axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `${strapi}/users/${getId()}`,
      data: bodyFormData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        // window.location.href = `/profile/${getId()}`;
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

I'm getting a 200 response but it won't update. I've checked the console for the state and this is the output

```
first_name: "Foobar"
last_name: "Bar"
address: "123 address"
city: "City Address"
country: "Philippines"
zipcode: "4026"
error: ""
avatar: "blob:http://localhost:3000/ecf9e21f-1081-4afc-80b1-1223cb6058bd"
```

this log is after the user inputs the data

I hope someone can help me

***This is the scenario***

the data from strapi using axios get request

```
first_name: "Foo"
last_name: "Bar"
address: "456 address"
city: "City Address"
country: "Philippines"
zipcode: "1234"
error: ""
avatar: "https://limitless-brushlands-81295.herokuapp.com/uploads/ed4648185e1e425c884beabb99a92695.png"
```

should be replaced by this data

```
first_name: "Foobar"
last_name: "Bar"
address: "123 address"
city: "City Address"
country: "Philippines"
zipcode: "4026"
error: ""
avatar: "blob:http://localhost:3000/ecf9e21f-1081-4afc-80b1-1223cb6058bd"
```

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused as to your model layout here are these fields added to the user model or are you using a profile model (with a relation to user)

Comment: these are fields added to the user model

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **axios put** method as below and check it out whether the response came or not. Please mention what is not updating , state updating or your response is not came?

```
const body = {body : bodyFormData};
const header =  {
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
}
axios.put(`${strapi}/users/${getId()}` ,body ,header)
.then(res => {
console.log(res)
})
```

In axios Ideally, First parameter is URL, 2nd parameter for header. But for POST or PUT 2nd parameter act as body and 3rd parameter for header

Comment: I tried but it returns a bad request error: files are empty

Comment: Can you show me the error from network tab ? How the url is passed ? Screenshot is better to understand

Answer (score 0):

I've checked strapi documentation about uploading files.Unfortunately there is no way to use PUT request. To update the image you must use POST request to overwrite the previous entry

[Strapi Upload Documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution for Uploading an Image as well as linking the entry with a model where you want to keep the links, in my case it is user.**

```
updateProfilePic(): void {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(`files`, this.file, this.file.name);
  formData.append('ref', 'user');
  formData.append('refId', this.data.user.id);
  formData.append('source', 'users-permissions');
  formData.append('field', '<name of the key where you want to store image urls>');
```

}

Comment: are you using PUT or POST?

Comment: I have used POST.

Comment: I don't think it will edit data, but it will create a new data